# Create multiple copies of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create multiple copies of an array, copies would only be a maximum of 5. I've been trying to do it this way.

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
  numbersCopy[i] = numbers;
}

console.log(numbersCopy);
```

But I'm getting circular object reference. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can spread numbers in a new array: `numbersCopy[i] = [...numbers]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could also use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = Object.assign([], numbers);  // <-- shallow clone array

numbers[0] = 22  // <-- modify original array

console.log(numbersCopy)  // [1,2,3]
```

Or could use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = numbers.concat()  // <-- shallow clone array

numbers[0] = 22  // <-- modify original array

console.log(numbersCopy)  // [1,2,3]
```

Or [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = Array.from(numbers)  // <-- shallow clone array

numbers[0] = 22  // <-- modify original array

console.log(numbersCopy)  // [1,2,3]
```

And as already pointed out [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [ES6 spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = numbers.slice()  // <-- shallow clone array

// or

let numbersCopy2 = [...numbers]  // <-- shallow clone array

console.log(numbersCopy)   // [1,2,3]
console.log(numbersCopy2)  // [1,2,3]
```

**Note** that this is all fine for `array of primitives`. With array of objects things are different since you have to individually clone each object via Object.assign / spread etc.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `numbers` holds a reference to the array, and you are copying this reference into the new array, so you will get an array with multiple references to the same `object` (an `array` is a special type of `object` in Javascript). One possible solution to create a new clone of the array every time is to spread `numbers` into a new array:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{  
    numbersCopy[i] = [...numbers];
}

console.log(numbersCopy);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Also, you can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to do something like this:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = Array.from({length: 5}, _ => [...numbers]);
console.log(numbersCopy);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: is there a way that I can use it without using the spread operator?

Comment: Yea, check the others answers, you can use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) without arguments too.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like:  "I want a new array, which copies up to the first five elements of the old array".  The function for that is `slice()`.

```
const oldArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
const newArray = oldArray.slice(0,5); // [0,1,2,3,4]
```

You can use slice to create copies in theses ways:

1. `oldArray.slice()` = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = make a copy, same a =[...oldArray]
2. `oldArray.slice(-2)` = [5,6] = the last two items of the array.
3. `oldArray.slice(0,5)` = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] = the first five items
4. `oldArray.slice(5)` = take the rest after the first five = [5,6]
5. `oldArray.slice(2,3)` = take items 2 and 3 = [2,3]

Keep on hacking a JavaScript!

Answer (score 1):

If the array is a primitive array (containing no objects or arrays), you can use `.slice()`:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
  numbersCopy[i] = numbers.slice();
}

console.log(numbersCopy);
```

If it's not a primitive array, use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`:

```js
let numbers = [[1], {a: 2}, 3];
let numbersCopy = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
  numbersCopy[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(numbers));
}

numbers[0] = 0;

console.log(numbersCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` for a more elegant solution:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
let numbersCopy = numbers.slice();
console.log(numbersCopy);
```

Answer (score -1):

do you understand what you are doing?  you are creating one array, and then you are populating a second array by assigning the same single pointer to the first one, to elements of the second one.  there is no circular reference here, but there's no "copying" of anything.

look: after you do what you say you do, you can alter the initial `numbers` array, and the change is reflected in every member of the `numbersCopy`.  duh.  it's all the same `numbers` array, obviously they all change.

what are you trying to do, really?

and where what you do isn't what you expect?

Comment: I understand downvoting my answer, for it does not "answer" any question, but I do disagree with downvoting: I'm "addressing" the question, which shows a deep lack of understanding of what they're doing.  providing such well structured answers to such a question, does it help?